# OpenCV image type conversion

Tags: c++, opencv

I am doing conversions between an OpenCV floating point and an 8 bit image format and I just cannot see why it doesn't work.

```
cv::Mat gray;
for (float g = 0; g < 10; g++)
{
    gray.push_back(g);
}
// All good, values between (0,9 )
cv::normalize(gray, gray, 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX); //Still fine, all is between (0,1)
cv::Mat gray_8bit;
gray.convertTo(gray_8bit, CV_8UC1, 255); //gray_8bit is complete bogus with nans and what not.
```

I just cannot see why the last conversion doesn't work? I tried replacing CV_8UC1 with CV_32F and exactly as you would think the output gray_8bit is then between 0-255.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, `gray_8bit` contains expected values.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. I thought my OpenCV installation was broken, but ran it in a docker container with an installation I know should work, and I get the same results. 
I use the .at function for debugging the values. I noticed that .at<> seems to create weird results for seemingly non-critical casts. Maybe this is where the problem is.

Comment: You're quite likely using `at` with a type that doesn't match the datatype of the `Mat`. It's basically a `reinterpret_cast`. In this case, `gray_8bit` is `CV_8UC1`, so you must use `at<uchar>` (or any other alias for unsigned 8bit integer). Using anything else will result in garbage, or a crash due to accessing memory past the end of the allocated buffer. (That would explain why you're seeing `nan` while working with an array of bytes.. that didn't really make sense) | IOW the problem is not in the code you've shown here.

Comment: Yep, you are right. OpenCV doesn't do a cast automatically for this.